# Migration from generic OpenStack to Ubuntu Openstack

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape

Does anyone have experience and advice in migrating from a generic OpenStack cloud to one based on Ubuntu tools (including MAAS, Juju, Landscape, etc)?

We are hitting the limit on our install, and wish we had used Ubuntu Openstack from the start ... but now that we are up and running, are a little nervous about attempting a switch.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no real simple way of doing this once you're up and running without starting over.

We should perhaps in the future we could do something like migrating VMs from one cloud to another but we're not anywhere close to that, sorry.